# CodeIgniter CSS shows 404 error when uploaded to live site

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

**Background**

This is the second time I have tried to upload a CodeIgniter site to my server... I have tried all the top suggestions to get this to work, to no avail!

I am uploading codeigniter to my https://example.com/app

I am using HMVC Modules with codeigniter but that should not be causing these issues.

**Problem**

My CSS files refuse to load, they show a 404 error.

Here is my folder structure:

[image]

Here is how I am loading the files in my HTML templates...

```
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url() . 'public/css/bootstrap.css'; ?>">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url() . 'public/css/font-awesome.css'; ?>">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url() . 'public/css/custom.css'; ?>">
```

Here is my base_url() configuration...

```
$config['base_url'] = 'https://toucan-talk.com/app/';
```

And here is my .htaccess file (currently, I have tried a few different settings).

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

I am not sure what is going wrong here!

Comment: i think  u find public folder inside app folder .. open css `https://toucan-talk.com/public/css/bootstrap.css`

Comment: Nope, my root folder for the codeigniter app is https://toucan-talk.com/app

Comment: Did you try with Public? maybe it is case sensitive

Comment: You just nailed it Roberto. Thanks so much!

Comment: `RewriteBase /app/`

Comment: Hi Tpojka, why do I need to add that?

Comment: Check [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase). I am not sure if Apache would smartly determine document root in subdirectory tho. That said, it's always good choice set RewriteBase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `base_url()` returns `https://toucan-talk.com/app/` and when you add the css folder you get `https://toucan-talk.com/app/public/css/bootstrap.css` which isn't a valid path.

The easiest fix is to move the public folder so it is a sub-folder of app/.

The other option is to modify the string returned from `base_url()` and modify it to create the correct path.

This first line of code turns `https://toucan-talk.com/app/` into `https://toucan-talk.com/Public/css/`

```
<?php
$css_path = str_replace('app', 'Public/css/', base_url());
?>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $css_path;?>bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $css_path;?>font-awesome.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $css_path;?>custom.css'; ?>">
```